# Como dibujar una pirámide con asteriscos

Tags: java

Necesito que al, por ejemplo, introducir un 5 aparezca esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo es este:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num = 4;

    while(num % 2 == 0){

        System.out.println("Introduce un numero impar:");
        num = in.nextInt();

        if (num % 2 == 0){
            System.out.println("Has introducido un numero par");
        }
    }

   for (int numFila = 0; numFila < num; numFila++) {    //filas
        for (int numColumna = 0; numColumna < num*2-1; numColumna++) {   //columnas

            if (numFila <= numColumna){
                System.out.print(" * ");
            }else{
                System.out.print("   ");
            }

        }
        //Salt de línia per començar un altre fila
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Lo único que consigo es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando el código el problema es en el `for` interno `for (int numColumna = 0; numColumna < num*2-1; numColumna++)` en la condicional `num*2-1` la variable `num` no decrece y siempre el limite es el mismo en el ejemplo sería `4*2-1 = 7`valido para la primera fila pero para la segunda fila, para esta deberia ser `3*2-1 = 5`

Answer (score 1):

el problema es como haces los for anidados, y como gestionas la cantidad de asterisco respecto al número de filas.

Te pongo una solución usando la filosofia de crear primero los espacios y luego el número de asteriscos necesarios por fila:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num;

    do {
        System.out.println("Introduce un numero impar:");
        num = in.nextInt();

        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Has introducido un numero par");
        }
    } while (num % 2 == 0);

    for (int numFila = 0; numFila < num; numFila++) {    //filas
        for (int spaces = 0; spaces < numFila; spaces++) {
            System.out.print("   ");
        }
        for (int asterisk = 0; asterisk < ((num - numFila) * 2 - 1); asterisk++) {
            System.out.print(" * ");
        }
        //Salto de linea para comenzar otra fila
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

PD: Como bonus te he cambiado el while del principio por un do while para que no tengas que hacer esa asignación "fea" de num a 4.

Answer (score 1):

Mi solución usa una clase `AsteriskPiramid`, aunque no es completamente necesario.

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

public class AsteriskPiramid {

    int numFilas;
    int numColumnas;

    public AsteriskPiramid(int numFilas) {
        this.numFilas = numFilas;
        this.numColumnas = ((numFilas * 2) - 1);
    }

    public void print() {

        String spacio = "";  // el espacio en blanco al inicio de cada fila 

        for (int j = 0; j < numFilas; j++) {

            System.out.print(spacio); // primero imprime el espacio en blanco de cada fila

            for (int i = 0; i < numColumnas; i++) {

                System.out.print("* "); // segundo imprime los asteriscos de la fila + un espacio   

            }
            numColumnas -= 2; // cada vez se imprimen 2 asteriscos menos
            spacio += "  "; // cada vez se añaden 2 espacios en blanco al inicio de cada fila
            System.out.println();  // salta a la siguiente fila

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num = 0;

        while (num % 2 == 0) {

            System.out.println("Introduce un numero impar:");
            num = in.nextInt();

            if (num % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Has introducido un numero par");
            }
        }

        AsteriskPiramid piramid = new AsteriskPiramid(num);
        piramid.print();
    }
}
```

Despúes de recibir como input un numero impar, se crear un objeto `AsteriskPiramid` y se imprime la piramide llamando `print()`.